# Нужно ли закрывать локальныеIO-потоки в Java

Tags: java, java-stream

Если поток был создан локально, обязательно ли его закрывать в конце метода?

```
public void method() {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    ...
    fis.close(); //Необходимо ли это?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нужно закрывать, чтобы не было утечки памяти. Закрывая мы говорим сборщику мусора, что объект можно убирать. Если не хочется закрывать вручную, есть альтернатива: `try-с-ресурсами`:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.txt")) {
        //тут что-то делать с fis.
} catch(IOException e) {
        // обработка исключений
} finally {
        // финализация чего-либо
}
```

`FileInputStream` будет закрыт автоматически. В самом простом случае от `finally` можно отказаться совсем.

Answer (score 2):

Обязательно. При создании объект открывается для чтения и система должна знать, когда ресурс станет опять свободным. Также, в случае, если поток окажется не закрыт, может происходить утечка памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Leonis дело говорит. Причем **крайне рекомендуется** использовать именно `try-с-ресурсами` (при Java 7 и выше) вместо закрытия вручную в блоке `finally`